# Set FolderBrowserDialog to foreground

Tags: c#, installshield, folderbrowserdialog

I'm creating an Basic MSI installshield installer. And for choosing instllation path i'm calling FolderBrowserDialog. Everything works OK except FolderBrowserDialog appers in background. I would like to set it to be a foreground window. This code always returns true and works fine if there is no other window open.

How can I check if dialogHandle is my dialog handle?

Here is my method:

```
/// <param name="fPath">INSTALLPATH</param>
    /// <param name="handle">installshield handle</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string NetworkFolderDialog(string sFilePath, IntPtr handle)
    {

        FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        IntPtr handle2 = GetDesktopWindow();
        IntPtr dialogHandle = GetWindow(handle2, 5);

        bool set = SetForegroundWindow(dialogHandle);

        DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();

        MessageBox.Show(set.ToString());

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            return dialog.SelectedPath;
        else
            return sFilePath;
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the following lines from your code:

```
IntPtr handle2 = GetDesktopWindow();
IntPtr dialogHandle = GetWindow(handle2, 5);

bool set = SetForegroundWindow(dialogHandle);
```

Comment: I tried this. But it doesn't work at all. 
FolderBrowserDialog always appears behind install window.

Comment: Can you get the handle of the installation window? If so you can use the overloaded version of ShowDialog (dialog.ShowDialog(this)).

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion about this here: [Custom Installer in .Net showing Form behind installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213498/custom-installer-in-net-showing-form-behind-installer)