# Custom Installer in C#.Net

Tags: c#, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom Installer in .Net showing Form behind installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213498/custom-installer-in-net-showing-form-behind-installer)

I have problem in creating custom installer.
I also implement custom installer in and also show my own created forms but it display back side of default installer screen.
I want to hide default installer screen and show my own created screen in installer package.

Any one have any idea???